# Batch PCollection in Beam/Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a PCollection in GCP Dataflow/Apache Beam. Instead of processing it one by one, I need to combine "by N". Something like `grouped(N)`. So, in case of bounded processing, it will group by 10 items in batch and last batch with whatever left. 
Is this possible in Apache Beam?

Comment: Isn't `GroupIntoBatches` PTransform applicable here ?

Answer (score 3):

Edit, looks like: [Google Dataflow "elementCountExact" aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278697/google-dataflow-elementcountexact-aggregation)

You should be able to do something similar by assigning elements to global window and using `AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(N)`. You still need to account for what what if there isn’t enough elements to fire the trigger. You could use this:

```
 Repeatedly.forever(AfterFirst.of(
  AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(N),
  AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(X))))
```

But you should ask yourself why do you need this heuristic in the first place, there probably is more idomatice way to solve your problem. Read about `Data-Driven Triggers` in [Beam’s programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/)