# How to create groups of N elements from a PCollection Apache Beam Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to accomplish something like this:
[Batch PCollection in Beam/Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348085/batch-pcollection-in-beam-dataflow)

The answer in the above link is in Java, whereas the language I'm working with is Python. Thus, I require some help getting a similar construction.

Specifically I have this:

```
 p = beam.Pipeline (options = pipeline_options)
 lines = p | 'File reading' >> ReadFromText (known_args.input)
```

After this, I need to create another `PCollection` but with a `List` of N rows of "lines" since my use case requires a group of rows. I can not operate line by line.

I tried a `ParDo` Function using variables for count associating with the counter N rows and after `groupBy` using `Map`. But these are reset every 1000 records, so it's not the solution I am looking for. I read the example in the link but I do not know how to do something like that in Python.

I tried saving the counters in Datastore, however, the speed difference between Dataflow reading and writing with Datastore is quite significant.

What is the correct way to do this? I don't know how else to approach it. 
Regards.

Comment: Could you rephrase what do you want to achieve? Do you want to be able to have whole input file (all lines) as single list?

Comment: Hi @MarcinZablocki, no, I want a PCollection of List with N rows from the input file, for example: if N is 2 and the input is "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" where the comma is a jump of line, I want a PCollection that is something like this: PCollection[List(1,2), List(3,4), List(5,6), List(7,8)]

Comment: So what if the input is "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" and N=2? How should the output PCollection look like?

Comment: PCollection is **unordered**. Unless your input contains the order information (say `ReadFromText` returns tuples of `(sequence number, element)`), this kind of deterministic grouping is tricky to do with beam (need `State` or data-driven triggers). If your pipeline doesn't require deterministic grouping, you can maintain a buffer of size N in your DoFn and flush the buffer every time when it's full (or in `finish_bundle`).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267159/beam-dataflow-2-2-0-extract-first-n-elements-from-pcollection) question seems to be similar to yours - the answer was to use the [Top transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Top.html).

Comment: The order isn't important, the important is have in the output tuples of N registers, the question is transform for example, a PCollection in a List of PCollections of N rows.

Answer (score 10):

Assume the grouping order is not important, you can just group inside a `DoFn`.

```py
class Group(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, n):
     self._n = n
     self._buffer = []

  def process(self, element):
     self._buffer.append(element)
     if len(self._buffer) == self._n:
        yield list(self._buffer)
        self._buffer = []

  def finish_bundle(self):
     if len(self._buffer) != 0:
        yield list(self._buffer)
        self._buffer = []

lines = p | 'File reading' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)
          | 'Group' >> beam.ParDo(Group(known_args.N)
          ...
```

Comment: I get this error when I run it: `RuntimeError: Finish Bundle should only output WindowedValue type but got <class 'list'>`

Comment: And how does this take into account that sum elements might be leftover towards the end? For example, in case we have an odd number of elements then 1 element wont' be processed.